# Question about Karate using URL with query parameter

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin, karate

I am trying to write a test case in Karate. The URL has a '?' in it, and am not sure how to handle it. I've pasted below the code below:

```
Feature: WorkOrder API


Background:
* configure ssl = true
* url 'http://blahblah/v1/workorders/activitydetails?WorkOrderID='

Scenario Outline: Get all the workorder activity details by valid workorder id

Given path <ID>
When method get
Then status <statuscode>
And assert response != null


Examples:
  |     ID      | statuscode |
  |  123456     |     200    |
  |  -56874     |     400    |
  |  1.2345     |     422    |
  |  'abcdefg'  |     422    |
  |  'd1d30ecc-a031-4f73-8687-e2b2f7e49c2b' | 422 |
```

How should I write the URL so that it can check against my examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I've figured it out. I had to write as such:

```
Feature: WorkOrder API


Background:
* configure ssl = true
* url 'http://blahblah/v1/workorders/activitydetails?WorkOrderID='

Scenario Outline: Get all the workorder activity details by valid workorder id

Given path 'activitydetails'
And param WorkOrderID = <ID>
When method get
Then status <statuscode>
And assert response != null


Examples:
  |     ID      | statuscode |
  |  123456     |     200    |
  |  -56874     |     400    |
  |  1.2345     |     422    |
  |  'abcdefg'  |     422    |
  |  'd1d30ecc-a031-4f73-8687-e2b2f7e49c2b' | 422 |
```